# If closed surface integral of cross product of two vectors is zero, what can i know about the vectors?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-fields

**For vector $\vec{E}, \vec{H}$**

**(a) $ \iint_{S} (\vec{E}\times\vec{H})\cdot d\vec{s} = 0 $** (The integral here is closed integral but i cannot use \oiint here)

**then what can i know about vectors $\vec{E}, \vec{H} $?**

I thought about $ d\vec{s} = \hat{n} ds $

$ (\vec{E}\times\vec{H})\cdot \hat{n} = \hat{n} \cdot (\vec{E}\times\vec{H}) = \vec{E}\cdot(\vec{H}\times\hat{n}) = \vec{H} \cdot (\hat{n}\times\vec{E})$

Then, 
If

(1) $\hat{n}\times\vec{E}=0$ on surface $S$

or (2) $\hat{n}\times\vec{H}=0$ on surface $S$

or (3) $\hat{n}\times\vec{E}=0$ on a portion of $S$ and $\hat{n}\times\vec{H}=0$ on the rest of $S$

is satisfied, $ \iint_{S} (\vec{E}\times\vec{H})\cdot d\vec{s} = 0 $

Ie, if (1) or (2) or (3) is satisfied, (a) is correct.
But I don't know that if (a) is correct, whether (1) or (2) or (3) is the only possible cases or not.  How do you think??